# How to exponentiate two big floats

Tags: go, bigfloat

I am using golang `math/big` package, and when I read the documentation, i could not find a exponentiate function for bigFloats. I found something called MantExp but i do not know what this means. How can I exponent floating point bignumbers in go?

Comment: I think in that example, they are doing exponentiation with bigints not bigfloats

Comment: oh there is no built in function, so the example is correct. Thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer this [golang.org example](http://golang.org/src/math/big/example_test.go)  ( You may get some  hints from this example, **See Line 97** in this example)